# Explicitly bracket Python expression based on evaluation order

Tags: python, operator-precedence

Sometimes it is not obvious whether I need brackets in an expression.  Consider:

```
arr == 1 | arr == 2  # evaluates as: arr == ((1 | arr) == 2)
```

```
a, b = 3, 4; print(a, b == 3, 4)  # prints: 3, False, 4
```

I'm trying to create a CLI tool that lets me feed in an expression, and outputs the same expression explicitly bracketed.

What would be a clean approach? Does Python provide something like this out of the box?

REF: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: I don't get this, Python is doing it "correctly" according to the precedence unless you specify parenthesis, isn't that what parenthesis are for?

Comment: (1) You seem to be expecting a function that will "read my mind" to do what you expect, rather than what you wrote.  This is a difference of opinion between you and the language definition.  In order to have a viable problem statement, you need to *specify* what you mean by the "correct" interpretation.

Comment: (2) "How do I design a function ...?"  You do this the way you design any function: specify the inputs and outputs.  Analyze that transition, breaking it down into its component steps.  Teaching you how to do this is not a Stack Overflow issue.  Even working through the high-level steps for such a "DWIM" (do what I mean) function is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: My bad, sorry. The question was badly formulated. I've fixed it.

Comment: Do you want a function that inserts brackets according to the argument grouping you *intended*, or the argument grouping Python would *actually use* for the input expression?

Comment: (Also, `arr == ((1 | arr) == 2)` isn't how the first expression gets evaluated, because of [comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). Even if Python didn't have comparison chaining, `==` would probably be left-associative rather than right-associative, so `arr == ((1 | arr) == 2)` would probably still be wrong.)

Comment: Anyway, you'll probably want to use the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).